# Check any HTML Tag present inside TD Tag

Tags: jquery

is there any way in jquery to check if any HTML tag present inside TD

Example :

```
<td>
    <small></small>
    <pre></pre>
</td>
```

Comment: `$("td>*").length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `children()` to select the children element(all directly sub element) and using `tagName` to get the element name.

```js
$("td").children().each((i,e) => {
  console.log(e.tagName)
});
```

```css
table, tr, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <small>AA</small>
    <pre>BB</pre>
   </td>
   <td>
     <span>Test1</span>
     <ul>
       <li>11</li>
       <li>12</li>
     </ul>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Akshay Is it meet your demand?

Comment: Yes almost close